# How to recognise back action in html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a method from a class (jsf bean) when user leave the page by clinking back button of browser. I tried to use window.onbeforeunload, however it works for every situation. For example when user redirected with a link or button. How can I make it just for back action?

Comment: have a look at [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the history API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```